# Android - Position element over background image

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout with background image.
How can i set position of any elements (buttons, ..) over it ?

Thanks all.

Comment: Why did you don't set the image as background ?

Comment: How can i "click" on background image ?

Comment: ah okay, you can give your button an backgrund. Use this to fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `android:gravity=""

parameters and set to **top**, **bottom** and etc'